# Exercise: Construct two numbers using figures 4,5 and 6 whose product is as big as possible

Tags: arithmetic

Precisely what it says in the title.

Construct two numbers using figures 4,5 and 6 whose product is as big as possible.

I don't know whether I can use a same number again (4456, f.e.) or only 4,5 and 6 (I'm guessing it's this one).

I could go about it with trial and error, but would like to know the reasoning behind it.

PS: I thought about 654 * 645 because the bigger the number in the place of the hundreds, the bigger the result.

Comment: I think they mean for each digit should be used once in total, e.g. 65*4 and 54*6

Comment: I agree with @WW1 but maybe you should seek clarification from whoever has set you this problem.

Comment: If you are allowed to reuse digits in a single number there is no maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only 6 choices, namely

$$6\times 54 = 324$$
 $$6\times 45 = 270$$

$$5\times 64 = 320$$
 $$5\times 46 = 230$$

$$4\times 56 = 224$$

$$4\times 65= 260$$

Thus the maximum is $$6\times 54 = 324$$